# How do i set a Min / Max value starting negative and way back up to 0

Tags: c#, .net, math, charts

```
Y Axis
          5       10       15       20         25    X Axis
0

-100

-200

-300

-400

-500

-600

-700
```

It should look like that. So far I tried setting up

```
chart1.ChartAreas["Area2"].AxisY.Minimum = -700;//GetMinumumVal; //0 
chart1.ChartAreas["Area2"].AxisY.Maximum = 0;//GetMaximum; //-700  
chart1.ChartAreas["Area2"].AxisY.Interval = 100; // -100; 
chart1.ChartAreas["Area2"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
chart1.ChartAreas["Area2"].AxisY.IsReversed = true;
```

Is there a way I can use a start up of -700 way back up to 0 on the y axis?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Do you want the x axis to cross at y = 0 instead of y = -700? Do you just want the y axis to run from -700 to 0?

Comment: @mmathis sir i want y min value of -700 and y max value of 0 with interval of 100 so it should start below -700, -600, -500... until 0 on top..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, just remove the line setting `IsReversed = true` and it will be good:

```
chart1.ChartAreas["Area2"].AxisY.Minimum = -700;
chart1.ChartAreas["Area2"].AxisY.Maximum = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas["Area2"].AxisY.Interval = 100;
```

will set the minimum to -700 (at the bottom of the axis), the maximum to 0 (at the top of the axis), and the interval to 100.

Edit - if you do want the x-axis at the top instead of the bottom (like the drawing kind of shows), then you can set

```
chart1.ChartAreas["Area2"].AxisY.Crossing = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!! i should have done this 7hrs ago it could have save me from research and re arranging my codes to see what fits to solve it luckily all i need was this one --> chart1.ChartAreas["Area2"].AxisY.Crossing = 0; which i haven't researched for it yet...